# can't update, can't do a factory reset

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, backup, factory-reset

I have a Nexus S running Android 2.3.4. For a while now it's been trying to prompt me to install newer versions.  Every time I try, it restarts, displays the cute robot error screen and doesn't come back on until I take out the battery and restart it. Pressing power+volume+/- doesn't help.

I also tried to do a factory reset. Same result.

Before I got this phone (it was a gift), the shop did something to it "to enable Hebrew." Not sure what exactly but I suspect they dinkied around with system files and that's what is causing this.

Anyone have suggestions for what to try next?

Comment: did they root it or is the software modified in any way after "enabling Hebrew"?

Comment: no idea. How do I found out?

Comment: My instinct: take it to a more reputable shop :-|

Comment: not even sure where the original shop is:)

Surely there must be some way to restore the phone to its original state though?

Comment: I've closed [your previous question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22905/981) as a duplicate of this one, since this contains some additional information (such as the Hebrew patch/modification). In the future, please try not to re-post questions. It is preferable to simply edit the original with additional info, which will bump it to the top of the active list, thereby getting it more attention.

Answer (score 2):

This a solution to bring your device to a stable, stock, factory default state.

**NOTE: this will wipe your device *(not the SD card)* and return it to stock, unrooted factory defaults.**

1. Download one of these two files:

   - [This file](http://www.mediafire.com/?r4ek1ndosppyz7k) if you want to restore to **Gingerbread**
   - and [this zip file](http://www.mediafire.com/?768oco0kb4reiqb) if you want to restore to the OTA **4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich)** latest update.
2. Extract the file you downloaded to your computer, in a location you remember.
3. On your phone, enable debugging

   - this is usually found by going to the home screen, then pressing `Menu` and choosing `Settings->Applications->Development` and check the `USB debugging` option
4. Plug your phone into your computer
5. Locate the `run.bat` file in the location where you extracted the .zip file
6. Run this file and wait for the process to finish.
7. You're done! Reboot and enjoy!

Comment: is it .. safe?

Kind of hesitant about something so framed in ads.

Comment: The ads are a product of cheap file hosting. This method and these files have been used and recommended by others on reputable Android forums and websites, and the file has been reported genuine by those users, by statement of use. Though the site will try to coerce you with flashy ads, rest assured the file you seek is pure.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind ending with CM9 follow these steps:

http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Nexus_S:_Full_Update_Guide

Answer (score 1):

Google has the official system images available for download [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images). You'll need to be familiar with the fastboot tool or learn how to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is really old, but I just needed and found working instructions for the factory reset of a Nexus S. They are at https://developers.google.com/android/ota, the relevant steps are:

4. ... use the key combination for your device (Press and hold Volume Up, then press and hold Power), and then select the Recovery option from the bootloader menu. The device is now in recovery mode and an Android logo with red exclamation mark should appear on screen.
5. To access the recovery menu, hold the Power button and press Volume Up once. The recovery text menu will appear.

From the recovery menu, you can do a factory reset that will wipe all your data.